# Solution from Derivative

Tags: calculus

I have a general question. Suppose I have the graph of a derivative of a function f(x). How can I go about finding the number of solutions where f(x) = 0?

[image]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2sa9.png)

Comment: You cannot (in general) determine that. For example, if the derivative is $2x$, then the function could have been $x^2-1$ or $x^2+1$. In one case there are no real zeroes and in the other there are two.

Comment: I see what you're trying to say. I have attached the link to derivative graph. I am unable to add the picture as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that the number of solutions to $f(x)=0$ is at most one greater than the number of critical points of $f(x)$

Critical points occur at values of $x$ where either $f'(x)=0$ or $f'(x)$ is undefined.

Your graph has one critical point so $f(x)=0$ can have 0, 1, or 2 solutions.

Comment: Is your first sentence a theorem? Does it apply to Polynomials or any equation. It is interesting.

Comment: I think that it is a consequence of Rolle's Theorem which applies to more than just polynomials ... 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem

Comment: I see what you mean. Does this have any connection with monotonicity of intervals? i.e. since the function is decreasing in (a,0) and increasing (0,b)?

Comment: I think that any function is monotonic on any interval that does not contain a critical point.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess an inflection point indicates 2 real roots so that $$f(x)=x(x-a)(x-b)g(x)$$ may be possible - It is tempting to try to find the derivative and set x=0 to get a better shape of f(x). Thanks.